# Reading from a Closed File Descriptor

Tags: linux, trace, file-descriptor, gimp, strace

I traced `open`, `read`, `close` and `dup` system calls in `gimp-2.8.22` using `strace`, with the following command:

```
strace -eread,openat,open,close,dup,dup2 gimp
```

In `gimp`, I opened an image named `babr.jpg`. The trace shows that this image was opened (file descriptor is `14`), read and closed. But, immediately after that, the same file descriptor (`14` is not opened after the last close) is used for reading. How is it possible?
Here is the relevant portion of trace:

```
read(14, "\371\331\25\233M\311j\261b\271\332\240\33\315d\234\340y\236\217\323\206(\214\270x2\303S\212\252\254"..., 4096) = 4096
read(14, "t\260\265fv<\243.5A\324\17\221+\36\207\265&+rL\247\343\366\372\236\353\353'\226\27\27"..., 4096) = 318
close(14)                               = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ahmad/Pictures/babr.jpg", O_RDONLY) = 14
read(14, "\377\330\377\340\0\20JFIF\0\1\1\1\1,\1,\0\0\377\355(\212Photosho"..., 4096) = 4096
close(14)                               = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/gimp-2.8.22/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-jpeg", O_RDONLY) = 19
read(19, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P[\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
close(19)                               = 0
close(20)                               = 0
read(19, "", 8)                         = 0
close(19)                               = 0
close(17)                               = 0
close(16)                               = 0
read(4, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
Gtk-^[[1;32mMessage^[[0m: ^[[34m15:09:02.956^[[0m: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
read(14, "\0\0\0\5", 4)                 = 4
read(14, "\0\0\0\23", 4)                = 4
read(14, "gimp-progress-init\0", 19)    = 19
read(14, "\0\0\0\2", 4)                 = 4
```

I also checked this using `Pin` and found the same result.

Comment: The file descriptor is probably reused, and thus unrelated to the previous file it was used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second file descriptor #14 is very likely a pipe between the plugin and Gimp (the handle being free has been reused). And you don't trace the creation of pipes.

From `gimpplugin.c`:

```
  /* Open two pipes. (Bidirectional communication).
   */
  if ((pipe (my_read) == -1) || (pipe (my_write) == -1))
    {
      gimp_message (plug_in->manager->gimp, NULL, GIMP_MESSAGE_ERROR,
                    "Unable to run plug-in \"%s\"\n(%s)\n\npipe() failed: %s",
                    gimp_object_get_name (plug_in),
                    gimp_file_get_utf8_name (plug_in->file),
                    g_strerror (errno));
      return FALSE;
    }
```